# How to convert UTF-16 Hex code to Emoji character

Tags: java, char, emoji, utf-16

I want to convert the UTF-16 Hex value to Emoji characters, for example, may have code like `d83dde0e` for the  sunglasses and `d83dde00` for the  Faces but using this hex code how I can convert into emoji characters can any one help me for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do for example

```
System.out.println("\ud83d\ude0e \ud83d\ude00");
```